# PowerShell - Get-ChildItem does not exclude directory

Tags: powershell

When recursively searching through a specific directory, `Get-ChildItem` will search starting at the root. I do not want to search through the `C:\Windows` directory. I want to restrict the search to the `C:\Docs` directory.
Here is what I am running:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem -path “C:\docs” -Filter "*crypt*" -recurse -ErrorAction Stop
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CSC' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -path “C:\docs” -Filter "*crypt*" -recurse -ErrorAction ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\CSC:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS> Get-ChildItem -path “C:\docs” -Filter "*crypt*" -exclude "C:\windows" -recurse -ErrorAction Stop
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\CSC' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -path “C:\docs” -Filter "*crypt*" -exclude "C:\windows" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\CSC:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

EDIT: TL;DR: User error. I do not have the C:\Docs directory.

I am editing this script, which is running on several servers. I am testing it on my laptop. I still don't understand why it would look through the rest of the file system, once it could not find the starting path.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - it works as expected for me. Is it possible that your quotes are some strange "smart quotes" character that MS Word has changed a regular quote from?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with you script too. Can you try this if it give the result you want.  Get-ChildItem "C:\docs" -include "*crypt*" -Recurse -ErrorAction stop

Comment: @alroc I am using ISE to write it.

Comment: @demo.b I edited the question to reflect the fact my head was up my ass. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I can confirm that passing a non-existent path to `gci` results in the cmdlet looking through the whole drive. That's...odd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like (I haven't searched enough) this may be a bug in `Get-ChildItem`; if you pass a non-existent path to the `-path` parameter, it searches from the root of that drive (at least for local drives).

Before calling `Get-ChildItem`, test for the existence of the path and you can avoid this.

```
$mypath = "c:\docs";
if (test-path -path $mypath) {
    Get-childitem –path $mypath –filter “*crypt*" -recurse -ErrorAction stop;
} else {
    Write-Warning "$mypath not found";
}
```